# Шаблон функции, который позволил бы применять заданную функцию многократно

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Пусть надо написать шаблонную функцию такого вида.

```
deep<func, 2>(1);    // func(func(1))
```

```
template<auto foo, size_t depth, typename... Args>
auto deep(Args&&... args)
{
    ...
    auto result = deep<foo, depth - 1>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    ...
    return result;
}
```

Тут напрашивается еще одна шаблонная функция deep с частичной специализацией, которая бы просто вызывала исходную функцию. Что-то по типу

```
template<auto foo, size_t depth = 0, typename... Args>
auto deep(Args... args)
{
    return foo(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Но в c++ нет частичной специализации шаблонной функции.
Можно ли это как-то обойти, не используя классы?

Comment: `if constexpr` не поможет?...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно что-то типа

```
template<size_t depth, typename Func, typename... Args>
auto deep(Func foo, Args&&... args)
{
    if constexpr(depth != 0)
        return foo(deep<depth-1>(foo, std::forward<Args>(args)...));
    else
        return foo(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

[Так](https://ideone.com/SqFOPl) сойдет?

Только вот как по мне, `Args...args` излишне, ибо второй и последующие вызовы `foo` применяются к *единственному аргументу*, каковой одновременно является и возвращаемым типом (или приводимым).

Да и разворот во время компиляции мне кажется излишним. Вот так не хотите?

```
template<typename Func, typename Arg>
auto deep(size_t depth, Func foo, Arg arg)
{
    auto res = foo(arg);
    for(;depth-->0;res = foo(res));
    return res;
}
```

Comment: С if constexpr решение действительно выглядит просто и эффективно.
Пытался с enable_if, но там возникало много сопутствующих проблем.
А чем плох разворот во время компиляции? 
То, как вы предложили решение тоже подходит, но именно хотел попрактиковаться с метапрограммированием

Comment: С разворотом во время компиляции — это мое личное мнение? но мне кажется, что это менее красиво, нет? https://godbolt.org/z/8Tsqs4v4r

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Вы у нас главспец по концептам... Что-то никак не могу в последний шаблон корректно засунуть ограничение, чтоб `Func` была только допустимой функцией, могла принимать `Arg` и его же возвращать. Не поможете?

Comment: Меня призвали, и я пришел. :) Мне приходит в голову только `requires std::same_as<decltype(foo(arg)), Arg>`. Кстати, уведомление на @ не пришло - похоже потому, что я не писал тут комментов.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat А `is_invocable` — это тут не годится? Я (безуспешно) пробовал через него.

Comment: Может и годится, но он принимает еще всякую фигню типа указателей на члены. Тогда надо и при вызове использовать `std::invoke`, чтобы совпадало.